# jpa 2.0 criteria api expression for sql minus

Tags: sql, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

How do you create a jpa Criteria expression that is equivalent to the sql minus statement

example

```
  SELECT mod_code
  FROM SRS.Table1
MINUS
  SELECT mod_code
  FROM SRS.Table2;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minus does not exist but you can do something like that:

```
select t1.mod_code from Table1 t1 where not exists 
(select t2 from table2 t2 where t2.mode_code = t1.mode_code)
```