# jpa 2.0: how to do a sql minus of a collection with a table

Tags: jpa-2.0, jpql, criteria-api

I am looking for a JPQL or Criteria expression to find a subset of integers(codes) in my collection which are not in the table.

Native Query for Oracle DB would be:

> SELECT column_value
>      FROM Table(:listOfCodes)
>      MINUS
>      SELECT code
>      FROM table1;

This is similar to the post here but not exactly what i want [jpa 2.0 criteria api expression for sql minus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923801/jpa-2-0-criteria-api-expression-for-sql-minus)

Any pointers/help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just query for the values that are in the table and in your set, and then take the complement of what the query returns:

```
List<Integer> valuesInTheTable = 
    (List<Integer>) em.createQuery("select a.column from Entity a where a in (:values)")
                      .setParameter("values", values)
                      .getResultList();

Set<Integer> valuesNotInTheTable = new HashSet<Integer>(values);
valuesNotInTheTable.removeAll(valuesInTheTable);
```